# Ruby on Rails multiple associations between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Here is my problem:

I have a model User. a User may be admin.
A user can send error report to a pool of reports and this report can be assigned to an admin

How would you link these two models (User/Report) knowing that an admin is a user?

I'd want a report.sender and a report.admin but I can't find how to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the relations like this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reporter, foreign_key: reporter_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :admin,    foreign_key: admin_id,    class_name: 'User'
```

And use them like that:

```
report.admin # => returns a User object
report.reporter # => also returns a User object
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot, but I'm not able to affect an admin do you know how I could do that?
`report.admin = user
NameError: uninitialized constant Report::user`

Comment: Is the `user` variable an instance of the User model?

Comment: yes it is. I'm able to create a report by doing
`@report = @user.reports.new`
but unable to assign it by :
`@report.admin = @another_user`
or
`@report.reporter = @ya_user`

Comment: Can you post your Report's model? (or make a gist if it is too big)